# Adding reactive-form elements dynamically makes them invalid automatically in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm work on a dynamic form, where the rows are generated as per the user requirements. but the problem is as soon as the user generate the new row, it automatically becomes invalid, without even touching it. how to avoid this behavior. Here is my form 
[image]

and when I just click the add button it here is how it becomes
[image]

here is my html file

```
<form [formGroup]="loanProductForm">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class='tableHeader'>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                    <td fxFlex="22" class="pr-4">Name</td>
                    <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Price</td>
                    <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Loan Term</td>
                    <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Quantity</td>
                    <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Deposit</td>
                    <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Total</td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr formArrayName="products" *ngFor="let product of loanProductForm.get('products').controls; let i = index">
                <div [formGroupName]="i" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                    <td fxFlex="22">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                            <mat-label>Product </mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName="productId" [id]="'productId' + i" required>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productList" [value]="product.productId">
                                    {{product.name}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                            <div *ngIf="product.get('productId').errors?.required &&
                                                    product.get('productId').touched">
                                ProductId is required
                            </div>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td fxFlex="15">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                            <mat-label>Price </mat-label>
                            <input type='number' matInput formControlName="price" [id]="'price' + i" name="" placeholder="Price" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td fxFlex="15">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                            <mat-label>Loan Term </mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName="loanTermId" [id]="'loanTermId' + i" required>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let loanTerm of loanTermList" [value]="loanTerm.loanTermId">
                                    {{loanTerm.numberOfMonths}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td fxFlex="15">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                            <mat-label>Quantity </mat-label>
                            <input type='number' formControlName="quantity" [id]="'quantity' + i" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Quantity" required>

                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td fxFlex="15">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                            <mat-label>Deposit </mat-label>
                            <input type='number' formControlName="deposit" [id]="'deposit' + i" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Deposit" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td fxFlex="15">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                            <mat-label>Total </mat-label>
                            <input type='number' formControlName="total" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Total" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>

                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td fxFlex="10">
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                        <button mat-stroked-button class='addBtn btn-style-2' fxFlex='100' (click)='addProductButtonClick()'>Add
                            <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<button mat-raised-button fxFlex="15" class="btn-style-1" style="align-self: flex-end;margin-right: 30px;margin-top: 15px;" (click)="addNewLoan()">Save</button>
</form>
```

and here are related code snippets from my `ts` file

```
this.loanProductForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      products: this._formBuilder.array([
        this.addProductFormGroup()
      ])
    });

addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required],
      deposit: ['', {Validators.required,updateOn: 'blur'}],
      total: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  addProductButtonClick(): void {
    (<FormArray>this.loanProductForm.get('products')).push(this.addProductFormGroup());
    console.log('Loan Products: ', this.loanProductForm.value)
  }
```

Even though I'm using `*ngIf` in html but it still makes the new elements invalid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we need to remember that if we don't specify buttons inside angular forms to be of type `button`, angular will assume that the button is type `submit`. So this is actually what is going on in your code, your form is actually submitted. And the angular material form as default paints everything red to invalid fields when forms are submitted.

So just add

```html
type="button"
```

to your `Add` button:

```html
<button type="button" .... (click)='addProductButtonClick()'>
  Add
</button>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qh6cwo-latzab?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.html)**

Comment: Thanks you soooooo much..
I was exhausted by trying different ways to not make the newly created row invalid, but nothing worked except your method .Thanks once again

Comment: Do you know git ? I've quick question about that

Comment: Well I use it at work, yes, but no expert by any means!

Answer (score 1):

You can try edit your addProductButtonClick() function to this:

```
addProductButtonClick(): void {
    (<FormArray>this.loanProductForm.get('products')).push(newGroup);
    const indexOfLastProduct = this.loanProductForm['controls']['products'].length - 1;
    this.loanProductForm['controls']['products']['controls'][indexOfLastProduct].markAsUntouched();

    console.log('Loan Products: ', this.loanProductForm.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `product.controls['productId'].invalid` in the *ng-if.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please write the complete condition

Comment: ` <div *ngIf="product.controls['productId'].invalid">ProductId is required </div>`